# Error deploying an app to JBoss 5 that was working fine on JBoss 4.2

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jakarta-ee

Im trying to deploy an application (.ear file) to JBoss 5, and I'm receiving the following error. The app deploys fine under 4.2.2.

```
15:31:33,172 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfszip:/C:/ASE/ext/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/all/dep
loy/UGC-WS.ear state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfszip:/C:/ASE/ext/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/all/deploy/UGC-WS.
ear/ugc-ws.war
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:177)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:545)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:304)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:205)
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:405)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:547)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.metadata.ear.spec.JavaModuleMetaData
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployment.metadata.JSEArchiveMetaDataAdapter.buildMetaData(JSEArchiveMetaDataAdap
ter.java:76)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployment.metadata.ContainerMetaDataAdapter.buildContainerMetaData(ContainerMetaD
ataAdapter.java:76)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployment.metadata.ContainerMetaDataDeploymentAspect.create(ContainerMetaDataDepl
oymentAspect.java:51)
at org.jboss.wsf.framework.deployment.DeploymentAspectManagerImpl.create(DeploymentAspectManagerImpl.java:121)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.BareWSFRuntime.create(BareWSFRuntime.java:61)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployer.ArchiveDeployerHook.deploy(ArchiveDeployerHook.java:84)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployer.AbstractDeployerHookEJB.deploy(AbstractDeployerHookEJB.java:43)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployer.AbstractWebServiceDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractWebServiceDeployer.java
:60)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployer.WebServiceDeployerEJB.internalDeploy(WebServiceDeployerEJB.java:112)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
... 19 more
15:31:33,203 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS F
OR DETAILS):

*** CONTEXTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

vfszip:/C:/ASE/ext/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/all/deploy/UGC-WS.ear -> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.metadata.ear.spec.J
avaModuleMetaData
```

That's the error message from the console, and I can't figure out much from that...

The application just contains web services and a servlet that loads on startup to initialize and cache some data.

We have an EAR file which contains a few JAR files (one of them being named ugc-ws.jar) for libraries that we use, and also a WAR file which has the web.xml to load a servlet - this WAR file also has the same ugc-ws.jar in it's lib directory because the servlet is inside that JAR. So basically we have the main EAR file, and within it multiple jar files, as well as a WAR file - which also has a JAR file inside it's lib directory. And the error looks like it's coming from the WAR.

This is the output from "jar -tf ugc-ws.war":

```
>jar -tf ugc-ws.war
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/web.xml
WEB-INF/lib/
WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml
WEB-INF/lib/ugc-ws.jar
```

Just for testing, I remvoed the .WAR file from the .EAR and the application deploys without any errors, but obviously w/out the data from the WAR, i can't use the application. The way I'm deploying is just dropping the .EAR file into the server\all\deploy directory.

I've tried splitting up the ugc-ws.jar into two separate jars, one with just the webservices and the other w/ just the servlet, but I still receive the same error.

Just weird that this worked fine in JBoss 4 but not on JBoss 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It is not weird.

JBoss 4.2 was NOT Java5EE compliant.
JBoss 5.0 IS compliant.

It seems to me that you have a problematic setting somewhere in your war.
The error appears only in JBoss 5 since correctness is enforced in this version.

Just a quick guess. Your jboss-web.xml might have the wrong dtd. 
[Check this out](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBPM-1911).

I also advise you to re-read JBoss documentation and especially the release notes
for 5.0 and any migration tips they have for users of 4.2

Comment: Here's a link to all of the JBoss DTDs: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossDTDs