# OSworkflow jar file not getting deploy on Jboss 5.1

Tags: jboss

I am trying to deploy OS workflow file on jboss eap 5.1 but facing problem on it.This jar file contains osworkflow-2.8.0.jar and i have seen posts on internet which says the ejb jar files create problem in jboss 5.1.

```
06,598 INFO  [CopyMechanism] VFS temp dir: 
C:\jboss-eap-5.1.0\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\server\default\tmp
17:10:06,801 INFO  [ZipEntryContext] VFS force nested jars copy-mode is 
enabled.
17:10:07,864 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_27,Sun Microsystems Inc.
17:10:07,864 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime 
Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
17:10:07,864 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 
20.2-b06,Sun Microsystems Inc.
17:10:07,864 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows XP 5.1,x86
17:10:07,864 INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=run.bat 
-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
17:10:07,879 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
17:10:12,801 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: 
http://127.0.0.1:8083/
17:10:17,332 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack 
Native Core
17:10:17,332 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] 3.1.2.SP7
17:10:18,145 INFO  [LogNotificationListener] Adding notification 
listener for logging mbean 
"jboss.system:service=Logging,type=Log4jService" to server 
org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl@82d603[ defaultDomain='jboss' ]
17:10:30,223 ERROR [ProfileDeployAction] Failed to add deployment: 
osworkflow-2.8.0.jar
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Unable to find class path 
entry ClassPathEntryImpl{path=mmra/WEB-INF/lib/oscore-2.2.5.jar} from 
osworkflow-2.8.0.jar
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructureBuilder.applyContextInfo(VFSStructureBuilder.java:188)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructureBuilder.populateContext(AbstractStructureBuilder.java:82)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:89)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1001)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:437)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:387)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:297)
    at 
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.addDeployment(MainDeployerAdapter.java:86)
    at 
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:61)
    at 
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at 
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
    at 
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
    at 
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
    at 
org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Child not found 
mmra/WEB-INF/lib/oscore-2.2.5.jar for 
DelegatingHandler@22970138[path=mmra/WEB-INF/lib/osworkflow-2.8.0.jar 
context=file:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/ 
real=file:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra/WEB-INF/lib/osworkflow-2.8.0.jar], 
available children: 
[ZipEntryHandler@15378051[path=mmra/WEB-INF/lib/osworkflow-2.8.0.jar/META-INF 
context=file:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/ 
real=file:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra/WEB-INF/lib/osworkflow-2.8.0.jar/META-INF], 
ZipEntryHandler@22682719[path=mmra/WEB-INF/lib/osworkflow-2.8.0.jar/com 
context=file:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/ 
real=file:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra/WEB-INF/lib/osworkflow-2.8.0.jar/com], 
ZipEntryHandler@16564336[path=mmra/WEB-INF/lib/osworkflow-2.8.0.jar/overview.html 
context=file:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/ 
real=file:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra/WEB-INF/lib/osworkflow-2.8.0.jar/overview.html]]
    at org.jboss.virtual.VirtualFile.findChild(VirtualFile.java:472)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructureBuilder.applyContextInfo(VFSStructureBuilder.java:184)
    ... 23 more
17:10:47,503 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment 
AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@2347435{vfszip:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra/WEB-INF/lib/oscore-2.2.5.jar/}
17:10:47,503 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment 
AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@2347435{vfszip:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra/WEB-INF/lib/oscore-2.2.5.jar/}
17:10:47,503 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment 
AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@2347435{vfszip:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra/WEB-INF/lib/oscore-2.2.5.jar/}
17:10:47,503 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment 
AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@24363946{vfszip:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra.war/}
17:10:47,519 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment 
AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@24363946{vfszip:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra.war/}
17:10:47,519 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment 
AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@24363946{vfszip:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra.war/}
17:10:47,519 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment 
AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@9389903{vfszip:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra/mmra.zip/}
17:10:47,519 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment 
AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@9389903{vfszip:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra/mmra.zip/}
17:10:47,519 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment 
AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@9389903{vfszip:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/mmra/mmra.zip/}
17:10:48,972 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
17:10:50,519 WARN  [JBossASSecurityMetadataStore] WARNING! POTENTIAL 
SECURITY RISK. It has been detected that the MessageSucker component 
which sucks messages from one node to another has not had its password 
changed from the installation default. Please see the JBoss Messaging 
user guide for instructions on how to do this.
17:10:52,316 WARN  [XMLLoginConfigImpl] End loadConfig, failed to load 
config: 
vfsfile:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/conf/login-config.xml
org.jboss.security.auth.login.ParseException: Encountered "<?xml" at 
line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
<EOF>
<IDENTIFIER> ...

    at 
org.jboss.security.auth.login.SunConfigParser.generateParseException(SunConfigParser.java:401)
    at 
org.jboss.security.auth.login.SunConfigParser.jj_consume_token(SunConfigParser.java:339)
    at 
org.jboss.security.auth.login.SunConfigParser.config(SunConfigParser.java:98)
    at 
org.jboss.security.auth.login.SunConfigParser.parse(SunConfigParser.java:57)
    at 
org.jboss.security.auth.login.SunConfigParser.doParse(SunConfigParser.java:79)
    at 
org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfigImpl.loadSunConfig(XMLLoginConfigImpl.java:440)
    at 
org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfigImpl.loadConfig(XMLLoginConfigImpl.java:405)
    at 
org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfigImpl.loadConfig(XMLLoginConfigImpl.java:375)
    at 
org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfig.startService(XMLLoginConfig.java:218)
    at 
org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:376)
    at 
org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.pojoStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at 
org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
    at 
org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
    at 
org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
    at 
org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:243)
    at 
org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
    at 
org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:111)
    at 
org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72)
    at 
org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:221)
    at 
org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
    at 
org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:125)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:52)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
    at 
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
    at 
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at 
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at 
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at 
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
    at 
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
    at 
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
    at 
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
    at 
org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
17:10:52,550 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction 
Service (JTA version - tag:JBOSSTS_4_6_1_GA_CP07) - JBoss Inc.
17:10:52,550 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property 
manager MBean and JMX layer
17:10:53,035 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Initializing recovery manager
17:10:53,566 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Recovery manager configured
17:10:53,566 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Binding 
TransactionManager JNDI Reference
17:10:53,613 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting transaction 
recovery manager
```

What could be reason for this problem?Thanks for your time.I read similar post here [Error deploying an app to JBoss 5 that was working fine on JBoss 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530735/error-deploying-an-app-to-jboss-5-that-was-working-fine-on-jboss-4-2)  but didnt get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snowdrop jar file is used to make spring 2 with jboss 5.1
This works:- 
http://www.jboss.org/snowdrop .Use the snowdrop-vfs.jar and make web.xml change to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause for this problem is that there are xml parser related jars in both your application and the jboss-as/lib, jboss-as/lib/endorsed directories, the jboss-as/server/${server-profile}/lib, or elsewhere in the classpath.

Among others, conflicting versions of the following jars can cause this problem:

- xalan
- xml-apis
- xerces

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your login-config located @ `C:/jboss-eap-5.1.0/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/default/conf/login-config.xml` is not well formed. Make sure the XML file is well formed.

That should take care of the last error. Once you fix that post your findings here again.